# Number of google custom search api results

Tags: google-api, google-search

I use bellow code for requesting google custom search but I can only get 10 result per request. I know it must be 100. Does anyone know what I should do to increase this number of results?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(
            "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MY_KEY&cx=013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a&q=flowers&alt=json");
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (conn.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if( output.contains("snippet"))
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    conn.disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [CSE API documentation](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/reference/cse/list).

> `num`: Valid values are integers between 1 and 10, inclusive.

If you want more than 10 results you'll have to paginate using the `start` parameter.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response but how can I paginate it? Like in only one request.

Comment: Pagination is pretty much by definition multiple requests. You might be able to [batch requests](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/batch) if the CSE API is new enough to support it.